# How to record sound with music playing in background

Tags: android, mediarecorder

In my application, i have to record sound with music. When i am clicking on record button , music starts and recording will starting too. User will sing the song and this song will record with music .

In my code song is not recording with music. it records only sound of user.  Kindly check my code and suggest me.

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    record_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(RecordVoiceActivity.this, R.raw.intro);
                mPlayer.start();

                long dtMili = System.currentTimeMillis();
                primarySongName=""+dtMili;
                // Date dt = new Date(dtMili);
                Toast.makeText(RecordVoiceActivity.this,
                        "Recording starting", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                currentDateTimeString = DateFormat.getDateInstance()
                        .format(new Date());
                Log.d("##################################", "" + dtMili);
                recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/Recordedsong_" + dtMili + ".3gp");
                recorder.prepare();
                recorder.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    stop_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(RecordVoiceActivity.this,
                        "Recording stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mPlayer.stop();
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    replay_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("############################", currentDateTimeString);
                Uri path = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/" + "Recordedsong_" + primarySongName
                        + ".3gp");
                MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(
                        RecordVoiceActivity.this, path);
                player.setLooping(false);
                player.start();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

In this code , M recording the song and saving in my Sd card. Then replaying from Sdcard . 
But song is recording without music which i am playing.

Comment: Hello Gaurav, your problem is solved or not?

Comment: my problem is same so please give me solution for it.

Comment: GauravGupta: How did u solve the problem??

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta : Can you please suggest us to solve this issue..